# What is the smallest iron golem spawner?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to create an iron golem trap, and while I can create huge ones (see screen shot below) I'm interested in making smaller ones.
[image]
I have tried several different variations, including this one, and they don't seem to ever spawn a golem.
[image]
There are tons of examples of farms on youtube, but from what I can tell they're all 1.2.2, granted farming in 1.2.5 is pretty inefficient, but I'm still interested in doing it.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Village Test]

12 doors on a side with 4 villagers per side.  The vilage 'center' is the middle point between the the 'doors' that are considered to be part of the village.  The golems will spawn in the middle and fall thru.  DocM has a nice [tutorial on youtube](http://youtu.be/xE04Ui90sQY) describing the mechanics in detail.  20x20x8 footprint for the main cells.

It could be that your layouts dont lend themselves to having a natural 'middle'  Even the 2nd picture with the doors all clustered together in the middle, there might not be room for the golem to spawn because the doors are there.

Comment: Any idea why the people are standing in water?

Comment: the villagers are in water because they have been known to glitch thru the walls.  a water source block for each corner forces them to the middle.

Comment: I built this the other day, and I had issues with villagers glitching through floors.  When I made the floors two thick stone brick, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

A village has to have over 26 people for an iron golem to spawn. I think it might only spawn when there is a risk to the town or the villagers are free to wander around the village.

Comment: Hmmm, I count over 26 people on the bottom screen shot.  And there's 21 doors.  Are the doors all "real" doors?  Everything I had read on the net indicated 16 people, and 21 doors, both of which I have.  I have gotten the bottom design to work by adding a lot more doors, and the villagers all constrained, with no threats in site (at least that I was aware of....)

Comment: A village is only a village apparently if the doors have a room on the other side for the villagers to live in. 2nd pic down.

Comment: No, an iron golem will always spawn if the criteria are satisfied. There's no need for real threats.

Answer (score 0):

I've built several variations of Iron Grinders based on classic design. Then I found Nims Tutorial on his ultra compact design.

It's awesome - roughly 12x12 (Get your doors correct). I use it all the time. You can build it one block above the surface and drop the golems into your underground lair. There's no need to build the Redstone filter system really. But Hoppers to fill more double chests don't hurt.

Just heed the warning, you cannot have *anything* but glass within 5 blocks in any direction of the chambers. Even 1 block, and you'll always find your golems spawning on it.

If you have Residence protection, make sure that clearance exists. If someone builds in that 5 space air gap, you're golems will escape.

My personal project is a One Chunk facility - Gold (Nether Frames above Iron Grinder), Iron & Zombie spawner grinder. In one chunk which makes for faster loads, etc. Park this "Machine" in a spawn chunk and go AFK - score.

I've been experimenting with Nim's Version and still am. Instead of lava, I tend to use cacti - slower but easier to get and less dangerous. I've got Nim's version double & triple stacked with corner ladders so the villagers can mingle and breed - not necessary. I've another design I'm testing with a layer of doors sandwiched between the golem spawn chambers so I can increase the villager to door count.

I'm also looking at the MC Wiki's for a better understanding of the door (Home) mechanics to find further gains & output.

Cheers, M.